# UIScrollView with multiple views (3) having issue when coming back from another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

First up, I am not sure this is a valid use case or wrong approach. Need advise and help. TIA.

I have a (Main) viewController connected to a NAV Ctrl

On Main VC, I have got ScrollView (which holds 3 tableViews, I could swipe horizontal back & forth)

From Main VC, I could launch another sub-VC thru

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reminders animated:YES];
```

When I am done in sub-VC, I use back button to come back to Main control.

I do not see any issue, when simulator is set to work in Portrait mode.

Issue, when I change Simulator to Landscape inside sub-VC and navigate back to Main control - where ScrollView gets messed-up with size, all over.

One othertwist, inside sub-VC I change to landscape, finish putting in all value and reset to Portrait mode and then proceed to Main Ctrl, then.. all looks right.

I have added below method in Main Ctrl to handle reset size of ScrollView, its subviews etc. no luck

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Layout gets screwed when coming back from the second view controller?

Comment: Thanks **sha** for checking. ScrollView is not properly showing up. Its frame/bounds gets messed up. When I manually reset orientation back to Portrait, it is back to normal.

Comment: Does the rotation work when Main VC the top view controller (when you have not pushed any views)?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Yes, when I do manual rotation (from Portrait to Landscape & back, no issue) it does work correctly. Issue is only when I go to Sub-VC and navigate back to Main VC! Please see screenshot   http://postimg.org/image/byxn97zxb/

Comment: Do you use autolayout?

Comment: Thanks again **sha**, it did not strike me before. Let me give it a shot and update you here.

Answer (score 0):

I have ever come across the same issue, my problem is that I set the navigation bar hidden in the sub-VC, then when come back to main-VC, Main-VC's viewwillappear is called, at this time the mainVC's frame is not so accurate, because it exclude the NAV-bar's height.
similar problem will happe, if you set the ToolBar Hidden in SUB-VC and come back to the MIAN-VC.